# Linux shell script, use variable more than once

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've created a script that accesses a website with the use of a datafile and outputs the sites responses (one line XML) to an output file. I would like the output to start with the query of the datafile and then the response of the website. When I echo the query one one line and write it to an output file and then write the site's response to the same output file it uses two lines but I only want one line because I would like to end up with a comma separated file that I can import in excel.

This works but with having two lines of data:

```
while read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]
do
datatogather="$line"
echo $datatogather >>outputfile.txt
curl http://login:password@somewebsite.info/application.php?$datatogather >>outputfile.txt
echo >>outputfile.txt
done < datafile.txt
```

This doesn't work (although it shows the comma in the output file, so that line is being processed):

```
while read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]
do
datatogather="$line"
echo $datatogather,>>outputfile.txt | curl http://login:password@somewebsite.info/application.php?$datatogather >>outputfile.txt
echo >>outputfile.txt
done < datafile.txt
```

Stripping the output file of it's garbage data with sed was a breeze to figure out, even reading the input file into the site was very easy compared to figuring out how to use a variable more than once in a single line. Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Do one `echo` operation instead of two, and only one redirection instead of many, and use [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution) to capture the output of `curl`:

```
while read -r line && [[ -n "$line" ]]
do
    echo "$line,$(curl http://login:password@example.com/application.php?$line)"
done < datafile.txt  >>outputfile.txt
```

Note that the test is changed from `||` to `&&`, and personally I don't like unquoted variables, though `[[` is less problematic in some respects than `[` (but introduces other problems, IMO).

The only nasty feature there is that the double quotes mean that newlines in the website response are preserved in the output.  If you like living dangerously, you could simply remove the double quotes.  It would probably be better to revise it to map the newlines to spaces:

```
while read -r line && [[ -n "$line" ]]
do
    echo "$line,$(curl http://login:password@example.com/application.php?$line | tr '\n' ' ')"
done < datafile.txt  >>outputfile.txt
```

Note that you're liable to have problems if the output from the website includes any commas in its output, but you've not (yet) asked about that.

You do not want to put the `tr` operation outside the loop; you want a newline at the end of each `echo`, so this would be bad:

```
while read -r line && [[ -n "$line" ]]
do
    echo "$line,$(curl http://login:password@example.com/application.php?$line)"
done < datafile.txt | tr '\n' ' ' >>outputfile.txt
```

Comment: You changed `read -r line || [[ $line ]]` into `read -r line && [[ $line ]]`. This completely changes the meaning of the code.

Comment: The former case is a way to deal with [incomplete lines](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_194)—and hence files that are not [text file](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xbd_chap03.html#tag_21_03_00_68) (I really dislike the fact that more and more people think that it's smart and it looks cool to do `read -r line || [[ $line ]]` when they don't even know what a [line](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_205) is.

Comment: The latter case will break the loop as soon as there's an empty line (or on incomplete lines).

Comment: The quotes inside `[[` are mandatory on the rhs of equalities. Here it's safe to use `[[ -n $line ]]` or even better `[[ $line ]]`. Now you're mention quotes: you should definitely quote the address `http://login:password@example.com/application.php?$line` in the `curl` statement! you clearly have a glob character `?` and a variable expansion! _this_ is where you _need_ quotes_.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Only thing is that I get a line break in my output. it shows the line value with the comma on one line and the output on the other line. My input datafile.txt has a variable on each line, the output created from the website is also a variable (xml-string) on each line. The following doesn't work: `echo "$(echo "$line" | tr '\n' ' '),$(curl login:password@example.com/application.php?$line)"`

Comment: @ChristiaanHeerze What do you mean by _My input datafile.txt has a variable on each line_? can you show a (representative) sample of your file `datafile.txt`?

Comment: My datafile is a windows text file with on line 1 a variable (licenseplate) on line 2 a variable (licenseplate) and so forth. In my outputfile on line 1 there is the variable from my datafile (line 1), on line 2 there is the comma and the output of the website (XML), on line 3 there is the variable from my datafile (line 2) and on line 4 there is the comma and the output of the website (XML).

Comment: I've changed the fileformat to unix and now all works fine :-)

Comment: Using files in Unix format with NL instead of CRLF line endings and with a terminal newline makes the most sense. If you have to deal with vagrant formats, it is usually best to make them canonical Unix text files ASAP. Some commands will deal with unorthodox file formats; others don't.

Comment: Maybe there is some nicer way to do it, but I've added the following to the beginning of my script: `dos2unix datafile.txt` and `chmod +x datafile.txt`.
The script is working fine, thanks all for the help and support.

Comment: You're welcome for the help.  The `chmod +x` is extremely dubious; text files are not generally executable and you should reserve `x` permission for executables, executable scripts, and directories (and sometimes shared libraries).  Anything else should not usually have `x` permission.